# VSCode debugger having issues with character encoding

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

This question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64849170/gdb-error-reading-variable-in-array-while-debugging-vs-code) but there is no answers on this questions.

When trying to debug `char` or `string` type, the debugger prints `<error reading variable>` or `Converting character sets: Invalid argument` respectively instead of its value.

This problem can be fixed by running `-exec set charset UTF-8` from the debug console while debugging but it is only a temporary fix, and has to be run every time on debugger startup manually.

Is there a way to permanently fix this issue? (I'd prefer not to change any system settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Launch.json` file, adding `set charset UTF-8` to the `setupCommands` fixed it.

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    },
    {
        "text": "set charset UTF-8"
    }
]
```

Comment: What if this fails? When I do this I receive an error: Cannot convert between character sets 'UTF-32' and 'UTF-8'